# how to get logger name inside winston custom transport function?

Tags: node.js, winston

I have two loggers:

```
 var category1 = winston.loggers.get('category1');
 var category2 = winston.loggers.get('category2');
```

And i need to get their custom names (or default).

```
CustomLogger.prototype.log = function (level, msg, meta, callback) {
   // i need logger name here! (category1 or category2 or undefined / default)
}
```

How is the right way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hotfix ..

```
// fix to get logger name as metadata
var originalGetLogger = winston.Container.prototype.get // winston.loggers.get(loggerName);
winston.Container.prototype.get = function(loggerName,options){
    var logger = originalGetLogger.call(winston.loggers,loggerName,options)
    logger.rewriters.push(function(level, msg, meta) {
        meta._l = loggerName;
        return meta;
    });
    return logger;
}
```

im overriding get fn to add rewriter, and with rewriter im adding logger name to metadata.

```
// now each log will insert LOGGERNAME to meta
var loggerA = winston.loggers.get('LOGGERNAMEA'); 
var loggerB = winston.loggers.get('LOGGERNAMEB');
```

if there is something better let me know. thanks.